# I got paid "for" or "by" the job?

Tags: prepositions

> I got paid **for** my part time job.
>
> I got paid **by** my part time job.

What I want to say here is "I got paid by working part time."
I know I can just say "I got paid", but I want to say that I earned some money "from working part time job."

Then which preposition should I use here?

Comment: You can also be "paid by the job", which means you get paid after each job is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the preposition '**for**' as you were paid for an action you did, whereas '**by**' is assuming that the part time job paid you instead of the company, which sounds seemingly less reputable? *Your* **best bet is saying *'for'***, *either way. '**by**' is usually used with **passive sentences**, or the way something is done. Check **ecenglis**h for more info. Best of luck.

> https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-use